# rewriting a URL where a subfolder should not be visible

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domains setup with my webspace (all via a hosting provider)

So `www.maindomain.example` links to `/maindomain` on my webspace. `www.domain2.example` links to `/domain2` on my webspace. Pretty simple so far.

However as soon as I place another folder into one of those directories the `folder` of the domain itself gets mentioned in the `URL` again.

So imagine this … I have a folder `test` inside `maindomain`. In that case the URL to this folder is not `www.maindomain.example/test` but `www.maindomain.example/domain2/test`. So the `maindomain` directory name that is repeated in the url.

Why is that? Is there a way to make that go away via `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess`?

I found this in the `.htaccess` file on the root of my

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maindomain/
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maindomain%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maindomain%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maindomain/$1 [L]
```

However, since I'm not much of a server-guru I can't figure out what that actually means.

Comment: Did you post the complete `.htaccess` file? There might be other directives and if I don't see them I might give you wrong counsel.

Comment: Well, this is all! See my comment in your answer underneath! Without those lines the urls wouldn't work. I just want `/maindomain/` not shown in my address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect, Change URLs or Redirect HTTP to HTTPS in Apache - Everything You Ever Wanted to Know About Mod\_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/redirect-change-urls-or-redirect-http-to-https-in-apache-everything-you-ever)

Answer (score 0):

The first `RewriteCond` checks whether the uri does NOT start with `/maindomain/`.

The second and the third check the existense of the file as a normal file OR as a directory.

Then if all conditions are fulfilled, rewrite in prepending `/maindomain/` to the already existing URL.

Now to your problem. You have the directory `{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maindomain/test/` and want it to be reachable from `www.maindomain.com/test`. This additional lines does the work. Insert it **just below** `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /maindomain/test/$1 [L]
```

This takes any URI starting with `/test/` and redirects it to `/maindomain/test`. The `[L]` part means, stop **this** round of redirecting here (and don't evaluate the four lines below) and start a new round.

Attention: this is not tested (since I don't have access to your system). URL Rewriting often needs some testing to get it right. StackOverflow is not the right medium to give you support. You need to **learn** URL Rewriting yourself or hire someone who knows it.

Comment: Well, I see! Without those lines mentioned above the desired url I want doesn't work at all. Right now when calling `maindomain.com/test` it automatically redirects to `maindomain.com/maindomain/test` and works! When commenting out the lines above `maindomain.com/test` leads to a 404. So the lines above are needed for it to work. However I wonder if I can add an additional rule that "hides" the `/maindomain/` directory from the url so that the called url `maindomain.com/test` stays like this in the address bar and WORKS.

Comment: Thank you for your update! However, this doesn't work for me. Moreover is there no way of defining a "variable" for `test` so I don't have to define a seperate rule for every subdirectory?

Comment: As I have said, this needs some testing. You are on your own now. I flagged this question as too localized already because your question won't help anybody else.